# Doing Partition in only ubuntu 14.04 LTS?

Tags: partitioning, gparted

I was not asked to create the partitions in ubuntu 14.04LTS while i was installing it.After Installation i want to create a separate partition for my OS and my data.I have tried using Gparted but it is not worth for me.It is showing me this prompt when I am trying to unmount it, ''unmount the partition manually''.Please help me to do my partitions

Comment: refer https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowtoPartition

Comment: Include the output of `lsblk -f`

Answer (score 0):

First you will have to boot into the live disk. Then you can unmount the partition and proceed to re-size it. You cannot do it while you are in ubuntu because you are using the system itself.

Good luck

http://www.howtogeek.com/114503/how-to-resize-your-ubuntu-partitions/
http://www.howtogeek.com/116742/how-to-create-a-separate-home-partition-after-installing-ubuntu/

This should help you if you don't understand something.